# Automatically publish ClickOnce when build finishes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce WPF app that is intimately tied with an ASP.NET app.  The ASP.NET app launches the ClickOnce app at certain points, and the ClickOnce app is deployed in a subfolder of the ASP.NET app.

I have all of this working, and I understand that I can use the /target:publish switch when doing an automated build in order to update the ClickOnce files.  However, this doesn't help me with the developer experience.

Right now, when a developer makes changes to the WPF app, and hits Run on the web app, you don't see your changes in the WPF app because you have to manually go an publish it again locally.

Is there a way to invoke the publish behavior so that a ClickOnce app is republished when it is built inside of Visual Studio?

NOTE: I tried putting "msbuild /target:publish" in a post-build step of the WPF app but this caused an infinite loop I think because the publish target actually does a rebuild, which invokes the post-build step.

Comment: What is the reason why you would want to publish the application after every single build?  If your developers do not have the thought to immediately re-publish the application, is there a chance that they were simply re-building the application for test purposes?

Comment: I don't want to publish after every build.  Ideally I want to publish when the WPF app has changed.  When I'm in a change/test/change again cycle with the WPF app it is annoying to have to constantly publish in order to run it through the web app.  The web app passes URL params to the program so it needs to be run in that context in order to really test it for certain scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

In file Microsoft.Common.targets (v4.0.30319 x64), the Publish target is defined as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDependsOn Condition="'$(PublishableProject)'=='true'">
        SetGenerateManifests;
        Build;
        PublishOnly
    </PublishDependsOn>
    <PublishDependsOn Condition="'$(PublishableProject)'!='true'">
        _DeploymentUnpublishable
    </PublishDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target
    Name="Publish"
    DependsOnTargets="$(PublishDependsOn)"/>
```

Since Publish already depends on *Build*, just calling the *Publish* target in *AfterBuild* (or adding it to that target's list of dependencies) won't work.

However, since *Publish* just defines the order of operations by specifying its dependencies, you can get Visual Studio to publish your solution after every build by adding the Publish target's dependencies to *Build*'s dependencies. Just add the following to the very end of your WPF app's .csproj (or .vbproj) file. Note that the dependencies must be modified *after* including Microsoft.CSharp.targets (which in turn includes Microsoft.Common.targets).

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    SetGenerateManifests;
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    PublishOnly
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you only want to override this setting in some builds, just add the appropriate `Condition` on this `PropertyGroup`.